# Boost: what could be the reasons for a crash in boost::slot<>::~slot?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-signals

I am getting such a crash:

```
#0  0x90b05955 in __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator_base::_M_detach
#1  0x90b059ce in __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator_base::_M_attach
#2  0x90b05afa in __gnu_debug::_Safe_sequence_base::_M_detach_all
#3  0x000bc54f in __gnu_debug::_Safe_sequence_base::~_Safe_sequence_base at safe_base.h:170
#4  0x000aac05 in __gnu_debug::_Safe_sequence<__gnu_debug_def::vector<boost::signals::trackable const*, std::allocator<boost::signals::trackable const*> > >::~_Safe_sequence at safe_sequence.h:97
#5  0x000ac9c1 in __gnu_debug_def::vector<boost::signals::trackable const*, std::allocator<boost::signals::trackable const*> >::~vector at vector:95
#6  0x000acf65 in boost::signals::detail::slot_base::data_t::~data_t at slot.hpp:32
#7  0x000acf8f in boost::checked_delete<boost::signals::detail::slot_base::data_t> at checked_delete.hpp:34
#8  0x000b081e in boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<boost::signals::detail::slot_base::data_t>::dispose at sp_counted_impl.hpp:78
#9  0x0000a016 in boost::detail::sp_counted_base::release at sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:145
#10 0x0000a046 in boost::detail::shared_count::~shared_count at shared_count.hpp:217
#11 0x000a9fb0 in boost::shared_ptr<boost::signals::detail::slot_base::data_t>::~shared_ptr at shared_ptr.hpp:169
#12 0x000aa459 in boost::signals::detail::slot_base::~slot_base at slot.hpp:27
#13 0x000aad07 in boost::slot<boost::function<bool ()(char, int)> >::~slot at slot.hpp:105
#14 0x001b943b in main at vermes.cpp:102
```

This is the code:

```
#include <boost/signal.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

bool dummyfunc(char,int) { return false; }

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    boost::signal<bool (char, int)> myslot;
    myslot.connect(0, &dummyfunc);
    return 0;
}
```

It's the first time I am working with Boost and I am also completly new to the code of the project I am trying to port here.

That is why I would like to ask if such a crash could be in any way explained by Boost or if it must be unrelated to Boost.

I already tried to understand the crash itself but I got stuck somehow. It seems that probably the std::vector, which is going to be deleted here, is messed up (messed up = memory corrupt). That vector is a member of slot_base::data_t. The deletion is done in the destructor of slot_base::shared_ptr. So perhaps the shared_ptr also was messed up - so perhaps even the whole slot_base was messed up. But in the code I have, I don't really see a reason why that memory could be messed up. It is even the first access at all after the construction of myslot.

Addition: What I also don't really understand is why the ~slot_base() is called here at all when I do the connect. But I also didn't found the connect-memberfunction. Is that a magic makro somewhere?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code as given, but it should be noted that it's trivial to corrupt that `vector` by doing something entirely unrelated - your other code may have a buffer overflow, and it "spills over" into the vector (or shared_ptr, or slot...).

Comment: Is GConsole::init() small enough to add to this question?  If it's large, how small can you make it and still get this error?

Comment: I have reduced the whole thing to a very simple testcase. Seems it is really unrelated to my other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. When I enable these preprocessor definitions (my Xcode does that by default in Debug configuration), it crashes:

```
-D _GLIBCXX_DEBUG=1
-D _GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC=1
```

I guess Boost (bjam) compiled without those and that causes such problems because the STL structures (like vector) look different in binary form when compiled with or without this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your `GConsole` class is not derived from `boost::trackable`.

When a signal is bound to a member function, it expects the member's object to exist, always.

You can either explicitly disconnect signals when member function's owner is destroyed, or you can derive the object from `boost::trackable`, which will do the maintenance automatically when the object is destroyed.

Comment: But GConsole exists at that point. That GConsole::init() function is called after the construction of GConsole. Also, it is right at the beginning, so the crash occurs at connecting the slot, not at disconnecting.

Comment: Another question maybe: Why is ~slot_base() called at all here, when I do a slot.connect?