# Boost: how to build Boost under MacOSX

Tags: c++, boost, macos

I am trying to build MacOSX universal binaries (I need at least i386/ppc for >=macosx10.3) of Boost.

I tried a lot of different methods and options and versions and it all fails in the end with this crash:

[Boost: what could be the reasons for a crash in boost::slot<>::~slot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823605/boost-what-could-be-the-reasons-for-a-crash-in-boostslotslot)

I guess this crash is because of a bad Boost build.

With Boost-1.41.0, I think the most correct options I tried were this:

```
./bootstrap.sh && sudo ./bjam architecture=combined macosx-version=10.4 install
```

Comment: Why say you need >=osx10.3 and then set `macosx-version=10.4`?

Comment: I got that command from some website. Also I am building another application with SDK 1.4 but compatibility option for 10.3 and that seems to work, so I just used the command as it was written on that site. But it would be nice if it would work at all, then I can later try for 10.3 if it doesn't work there.

Comment: I don't know exactly what bjams `macosx-version` does, but mixed targets might just be the source of your problem.

Comment: I tried without and same problem / crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was already the correct command. I found out about the problem with my crash:

You must use exactly the same STL preprocessor definitions when you compiled Boost in your project. I.e. you cannot enable _GLIBCXX_DEBUG or _GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC in your project when Boost was compiled without those.

Comment: Are those two extra defines added by yourself? Or are they used by default in XCode for debug builds? In the latter case, we might change Boost to use them by default, too -- if you point to a relevant documentation saying they are set.

Comment: They are used by default in Debug build but not in Release build. Also, this may depend on the Xcode version and on the project template you use. So you cannot really rely on that.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use MacPorts to install Boost. That will build it automatically for you.

http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=library&substr=boost

Answer (score -1):

Just installed from [macports](http://www.macports.org/) and hopefully this is good enough for you. Command below:

```
sudo port install boost +universal
```